# How to record filtered video for iPhone?

Tags: ios, video, video-capture, avfoundation

It is easy to record video by two ways: UIImagePicker or ALAssetLibrary.

But if I want to process each frame with image effect filter,then save result as video,how to do that ?
I can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to process each frame and save filtered frame to still image, but can not save them to video,my question is how to save them to video.
If using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput,it is easy to record camera to video, but can not put filter for each frame.

Thanks for any clues or comments.

Answer (score 1):

As others might have suggested OpenCV is a good choice, unfortunatelly it is super slow on the iphone when compared to other techniques, try using Brad Larsons GPUImage framework.

You can find it [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using OpenCV, which now supports iPhone. You can find directions here:
http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/04/opencv-vs-apple-iphone/

The advantage of OpenCV is that you can utilize a pretty large set of functions and transforms out of the box.

Comment: I am quiet familiar with OpentCV actually since 8 years ago. It is quiet good. The only point is that the speed is slow. IPP is the comercial version optimized for CPU with SIMD. But for iOS app, I highly prefer to see some GPU based or optimized open source to do that.